# Is it possible to add multiple attributes into an XML file?

Tags: xml, multiple-instances

Can it be done? Are there any restrictions? How do I properly add multiple attributes? Thanks!

Comment: It is, trivially, possible. Have you run into trouble?

Comment: It might be useful to [familiarize oneself with XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Ofcourse you can add multiple attributes to any Node of a XML file...

Eg.

```
 <node att1 ="val1" att2 = "val2"/>
```

I guess your question is probably ... can an attribute have more than one value ? 
The Answer to that is a no....

Please let me know if you wanted something else..